# Searchable.xml not found on build of instant app

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

The **feature/src/main/res/xml/searchable.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
    <!-- TODO https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config -->
</searchable>
```

is not found in my instant app on the build, nothing is in the base module except the styles. Error output line is:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: resource xml/searchable (aka at.mts.arnatomy.app:xml/searchable) not found.","sources":[{"file":"./arnatomy/base/build/intermediates/manifests/full/feature/debug/AndroidManifest.xml","position":{"startLine":53}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
```

The corresponding action in the **feature/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SearchableActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
</activity>
```

The layout of the corresponding text field in is **feature/src/main/res/layout/search.xml**:

```
...
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/search_hint"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
...
```

And the related code of the **feature/src/main/java/SearchableActivity.java** is:

```
...
AppCompatEditText text = findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                boolean handled = false;
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
                    doMySearch(v.getText().toString());
                    handled = true;
                }
                return handled;
            }
        });
...
```

where the method *doMySerach* just prints a Toast. *minSdkVersion* is 24 and *target-* as well as *compileSdkVersion* are 27. How can the *searchable.xml* file be not found? I also tried to but the *xml* folder in the base module, still no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the *xml* folder into the base module **and doing a clean rebuild** solves the problem. In an instant app the *searchable.xml* seams to be only allowed to be in the build module.

Comment: anything referenced in your manifest must exist in the base module, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44928134/6668797

Comment: Never read that on the docs of android.com, thanks for your explanation.